# How to give windows directory path in os.listdir(path)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, python-2.7

While I'm trying to give windows directory path in os.listdir() it gives error.
 My code snippet:

```
with os.listdir('C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\video') as entries:
```

I know that python takes '\' as an escape sequence but I cannot find any alternative on windows. The error given out is:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX
```

I've tried below solutions but it gave me some other error:-

```
AttributeError: __enter__
```

Is there any problem with my code:

```
import os
import moviepy.editor as mp

#location = os.path.join("C:", "Users", "Hp", "Desktop", "video")

with os.listdir("C:\\Users\\Hp\\Desktop\\video") as entries:
    for entry in entries:
        if(".py" or ".png") not in entry:
            video = mp.VideoFileClip("entry.name")

            logo = (mp.ImageClip("logo.png")
                      .set_duration(video.duration)
                      .resize(height=50) # if you need to resize...
                      .margin(right=8, top=8, opacity=0) # (optional) logo-border padding
                      .set_pos(("right","top")))

            final = mp.CompositeVideoClip([video, logo])
            final.write_videofile('o' + "entry.name")
```

Comment: add with `\\\` like this ```with os.listdir("C:\\Users\\Hp\\Desktop\\video") as entries:```

Comment: Use ```'C:\\Users\\Hp\\Desktop\\video'``` or ```'C:/Users/Hp/Desktop/video'```

Comment: I tried both of yours solutions and I got this error: "AttributeError: ___enter___"

Comment: place 'r' in front of the file path. Like this r"C:\\Users\\Hp\\Desktop\\video".Now python read it as a raw string.

Answer (score 3):

Either use raw strings which ignore the backslash as an escape character

```py
with os.listdir(r'C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\video') as entries:
```

Or use a literal backslash (an escaped backslash)

```py
with os.listdir('C:\\Users\\Hp\\Desktop\\video') as entries:
```

Or just use forward slashes. They work all over in Windows.

```py
with os.listdir('C:/Users/Hp/Desktop/video') as entries:
```

Comment: It gave me this error on all the 3 solutions you provided above: "AttributeError: __enter__"

Comment: To work as a context manager, use `os.scandir` instead of `os.listdir`, and iterate over `entries`.

Comment: I think any mention of using forward slash as the path separator in Windows needs a caveat that many cases in the Windows API require backslashes, such as "\\?\" extended paths and the shell [path API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/pathcch) functions. Also, some programs parse forward slash as an option switch in their command line and require the path separator to be backslash only, so first normalize paths passed in command lines via `os.path.normpath`.

Answer (score 0):

@Adam Smith's answer is correct. But I'd like to point out a mistake. `os.listdir` doesn't return a context manager (just a normal list), so using it with `with` keyword is useless. Call the function normally.

```
entries = os.listdir('C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\video')
```

and you won't get `AttributeError: __enter__` error.

`with` keyword is an automated way to call `obj.__enter__()` before the block and `obj.__exit__()` after it. If the object (here a list returned from `os.listdir`) doesn't have those methods, you'll get an error.

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir
- [https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.**enter**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__enter__)

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import moviepy.editor as mp

path="C:\\Users\\Hp\\Desktop\\video"

entries=os.listdir(path)
for entry in entries:
    if(".py" or ".png") not in entry:
        video = mp.VideoFileClip("entry.name")

        logo = (mp.ImageClip("logo.png")
                .set_duration(video.duration)
                .resize(height=50) # if you need to resize...
                .margin(right=8, top=8, opacity=0) # (optional) logo-border padding
                .set_pos(("right","top")))

        final = mp.CompositeVideoClip([video, logo])
        final.write_videofile('o' + "entry.name")
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better if you use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) python library. Such issues are handled very well in it.

```
from pathlib import Path
p = Path('C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\video') # Use any format
for file in p.iterdir():
    # Every 'file' is a 'Path' variable with full path
    file.name # Returns full filename
    file.suffix # Returns extension. e.g. '.jpg'
    str(file) # Returns path as python string
```

Refer [here](https://realpython.com/python-pathlib/) to know more.